# Am I overwriting my superclass definition in the subclass method if I use the same name as the superclass?

Tags: python, oop, namespaces

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354848/seeking-common-ground-between-object-oriented-structures-and-mathematical-logic) in which I was overcomplicating things. Dependency in OOP can either be enforced with inheritance or composition. In this example I try to use inheritance. I would like to model the following simple set of equations with OOP:

```
T = c_v*t/(a*h)**2
U = (T**3/(T**3+0.5))
```

Using the `__init__` and `__call__` methods and thanks to [this link](http://hplgit.github.io/bumpy/doc/pub/._basics004.html) which shows an elegant way of modeling mathematical functions using object oriented constructs I was able to do the following:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, c_v, a, h):
        self.c_v = c_v
        self.a = a
        self.h = h
    def __call__(self, t):
        return self.c_v*t/(self.a*self.h)**2

class U(T):

    def __call__(self, t):
        T = super().__call__(t)
        return (T**3/(T**3+0.5) )**(1/6)
```

Then the following:

```
>>> U_func = U(1.5E-7, 0.5, 12)
>>> U_func(100*24*60*60)
```

Outputs the correct result.

However the line 12 `T = super().__call__(t)` is bothering me a bit. Am I overwriting the class definition `T` there? I don't really want to do that. Also I don't want to have to make up a new name for `T` as a variable (not a class) there.

Is the `T` there limited to the instance method scope or am I actually overwriting the definition of the class `T`?

Comment: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)
 ... [4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I overwriting the class definition `T` there?

No. Variables assigned within a function are hidden from outside, in their own private "scope". What you are doing here is called shadowing a global variable, and is not recommended but won't overwrite it. Instead, you should just use a different name.  The function will only assign the variable in the global scope if you do the following:

```py
def foo():
    global bar
    bar = 'new value'
```

Comment: You mentioned that shadowing is not recommended. Could you indicate what is recommended in this case?

Comment: I guess you could use the same name if youre really good with python namespaces and know what you're doing. The fact that I am asking this question implies I am not so that might be a good thing to tackle next. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different variables named `T`:

1. A class is bound to the name `T` in the global scope of the current module.
2. An instance of that class is bound to the name `T` in the local scope of the function `U.__call__`.

They are completely separate, with the exception that inside `__call__`, you would have to refer to the class by a qualified name like `__name__.T`, since the local variable `T` shadows the global one.

Comment: It's a really good answer as well but unfortunately I have to pick one.